# Redactor removes article tag from HTML while saving

Tags: redactor, html-entities

I'm using Craft 3.x. I'm using the Redactor plugin in Craft. I have an HTML with an article tag (HTML tag). As soon as I save it, Redactor strips the article tag because of which UI goes for toss.

.
.
.

After saving, It simply removes these tags and keeps the inner tags.

Comment: I disabled the Purify HTML option and it allowed me to save article tags. Is there a way that purify option is enabled and plugin allows me to save article tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify custom HTML Purifier configs so that it will allow article tags and the Redactor fields will respect the configs.

See: https://github.com/craftcms/redactor#html-purifier-configs